# connect linux as client (odroid) with android apps as server via wifi with socket programming tcp

Tags: android, c++, linux, typescript, sockets

With sincerely.

I get a project that I should connect a humanoid robotic to android app via wifi in local network with router.
The humanoid robotic is using linux (odroid) with c++. But I never got the project like this before.

Do you know how I shall start my practice? if you please, what is the steps to do my project.

I prefer typescript for the app. because I use Nativescript. But if did not any source typescript. android native is ok

nb: I never code something like socket programming before.

Thank you

Comment: This question is too broad and likely not to get a useful answer. Please narrow the scope of your questioning. Do you have any documentation about how the robot communicates over sockets? Does it use TCP, UDP, ...? What does the data protocol over the socket look like? If you can't answer those question, you can't move forward with your project.

Comment: As @RemyLebeau said, your question is too complex. You should try seeking help at official ODROID forums: https://forum.odroid.com/